# Python: Writing into file fails without error - results in empty file

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to handle uploaded file and write it into certain place in my project.

The view, that handles the file upload is:

```
def add_data(request):
    # If something was posted

    upload_form = DataImportUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES) if request.method == 'POST' else DataImportUploadForm() 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if upload_form.is_valid():
            upload_form.handle_uploaded_file()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request, '/path/' ) 
        else:
            messages.error(request, ugettext(u"Could not import data"))

    return render_to_response('folder/add.html', {'upload_form': upload_form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And the form is:

```
class DataImportUploadForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField(label=_(u"File"), required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataImportUploadForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.max_upload_size = 1024*1024 #1 MB
        self.fileformat = None
        self.filename = None


    def clean_file(self):
        f = self.cleaned_data.get('file')
        if not f:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"No file uploaded"))

        if f._size > self.max_upload_size:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"Uploaded file is too large ( > 1MB )"))

        try:
            reader = csv.reader(f, csv.get_dialect('excel'))
            reader.next()
            self.fileformat = 'excel'
        except:
            reader = None

        if reader is None:
            try:
                dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
                f.seek(0)
                reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)
                self.fileformat = 'sniff'
            except:
                reader = None

        if reader is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u"Unknown data format"))

        self.filename = f._name

        return f

    def handle_uploaded_file(self):
        media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        file_location = media_root + 'CSV/'
        from core.helpers import ensure_dir
        ensure_dir(file_location)
        f = self.cleaned_data.get('file')
        dest = open(file_location + f._name, 'w+')
        logger.debug(dest)
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            logger.debug(chunk)
            dest.write(chunk)
        logger.debug(dest.closed)
        dest.seek(0)
        logger.debug(dest.read())
        dest.close()
```

What happens when i upload file is (according to logfile):

```
DEBUG 2014-01-31 12:04:46,034 POST URL: localhost.dev/path/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=683FesoraFTYLR7HHxfPuu3bb5xuzPYY&task=upload User: [me] Account: [useraccount]
DEBUG 2014-01-31 12:04:46,126 <open file u'/path/to/project/media/CSV/filename.csv', mode 'w+' at 0x54690c0>
DEBUG 2014-01-31 12:04:46,126 <FILE CONTENTS>
DEBUG 2014-01-31 12:04:46,126 False
DEBUG 2014-01-31 12:04:46,126 <FILE CONTENTS>
DEBUG 2014-01-31 12:04:46,817 GET URL: localhost.dev/path/of/next/view/ User: [me] Account: [useraccont]
```

And what i see is empty file.

at first i thought, that perhaps this is file permissions problems, but the CSV folder has 2777 perms. and all the folders up to media folder (including media) have correct permissions, allowing access to folder. After all the damn script does not fail to generate the actual file.

Can anyone please point out some of the reasons, why this file might end up beeing empty?

```
(project)alan@alan:/path/to/project/media/CSV$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 alan alan 0 jaan  31 12:19 filename.csv
```

Django version i am using is 1.4.2, python version is 2.7.5+. Nginx + uwsgi & virutalenv + virtualenvwrapper In ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Suggestion:
why don't you use CSV writer? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/outputting-csv/

Comment: because i do not want to start messing with file's original format. Client might want to use different csv dialect in next view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to flush the internal i/o buffer:

```
    # … your code …
    with open(file_location + f._name, 'w+') as dest:
        logger.debug(dest)
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            logger.debug(chunk)
            dest.write(chunk)
        dest.flush()
```

wait… in your log you show that:

```
    dest.seek(0)
    logger.debug(dest.read())
```

is actually working? Then the content has been written.

So either:

- it gets written to a wrong path because of a typo or some other error
- you're not opening the right file because of a typo or some other error
- or your file gets overwritten by something somewhere else in your code

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried it and the results i get are exactly the same.

Comment: did you try printing out the content of `f` in your code? because you're definitely writing in the `dest` file. Thus if there's nothing in it, it should be that because you just do not write in it.

Comment: Yeah i did. the f is django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile and if i log f.read() then it reads its contents out just fine. AS logging shows, the same contents are beeing written into file - after all i read the same stuff from writing into it. Why the file ends up empty is beyond me....

Comment: Hmm you bring up 3 points - first two i have tested - i removed the files. I tested against first two by removing the empty files from the folder - they were created again after running the view. So i guess they are beeing written into correct path and correct file is beeing opened/created. Third - file gets overwritten somewhere. I had not thought about this, but how can this be possible? The memory file is beeing read by csv reader too. Destination file is beeing opened in next view though. Perhaps something goes wrong there...

Comment: It seems your 3rd guess was right. I'll continue my investigation to see wtf is going on there :).

Comment: this is one of the reasons why it's best to use context manager blocks (the `with` statement), which makes the `f` variable exists only in that context, and thus may not be mistakenly reused later on.

Comment: yeah it wasnt used later on :). The problem was, that i was opening file in 'wb+' later on... but its not binary file and i did not actually need to write into it... just read. After changing 'wb+' to 'r' in next view everything started to work..